# SQL Error about syntax error(POSTGRES)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I always get the error on postgres sql can anyone help me

```
ERROR:  Syntaxerror in „(“ LINE 4: Liga_Nr int(1),
                   ^
********** ERROR **********

ERROR:  Syntaxerror in „(“ SQL Status:42601 Symbol:79
```

---

Here is my code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Liga;
Create Table Liga(
Verband varchar(90),
Liga_Nr int(1),
PRIMARY KEY(Liga_Nr)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Spiel;
CREATE Table Spiel(

);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Verein;
CREATE Table Verein(

);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Spieler;
CREATE Table Spieler(
PRIMARY KEY(Spieler_ID)
);
```

Comment: You can't create empty tables or refer to a non-existent column for a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Integer types don't accept a parameter. The correct code is:

```
Create Table Liga(
Verband varchar(90),
Liga_Nr int,
PRIMARY KEY(Liga_Nr)
);
```

If you want to store a small number, use `smallint`. You can read about numeric types [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html).

Comment: THx, it was clear for me after some minutes, but how can i give max range for integers like varchar

Comment: @user3669866 Use a CHECK constraint.